# Aggregate and non aggregate calculation tableau

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

The following calculated field is returning a non agg, agg error:

(
IF
[MaxDate] = TRUE
THEN
AVG(CASE[Sales]
WHEN 1
THEN ([Pending Revenue])

END
)
ELSE
0
END
)

I have tried using ATTR, but it says it cant further be aggregated, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: could you please provide some sample input data and the desired outpt in order to get a bettere understanding of the context?

Comment: Which of the fields are already aggs?